# Why is Spotlight draining my new M1 MacBook Air's battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, spotlight, apple-silicon

I purchased the new M1 MacBook Air 2020 a week ago, and the battery gets drained in about 2-3 hours of browsing the web (I use Firefox).

According to my Activity Monitor, Spotlight is consuming 94.02 of my "12 hr Power." Some people have stated that it's Spotlight "indexing" the entire MacBook; I'm not sure if that's fine.

Do I visit the nearest Apple store to get my MacBook replaced? Or what do I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spotlight goes through basically every file on your mac to show you relevant search results as far as possible. This means every *new* files has to be indexed, yet old unchanged files not. So the first question would be whether you're adding many files to your Mac or whether you have huge hard drives attached to it.

Comment: @X_841 I don't have any drive connected to it; I installed 5-10 apps like Spotify, VSCode, iTerm2, etc on my built-in SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that this behavior could go away on its own. This might be something that needs to be done once for your system and will use less power once it is fully done the first time.

The first tech-support measure you take in any case is to restart your Mac. This solves most problems I have in general.

Next I would try updating the Mac, an update could contain a fix to this specific problem.

At this point you could contact customer support and try to get them to warranty repair/replace it, or you could try backing up all your data and factory resetting the device. If you are not tech saavy definately get help backing it up first to ensure you do not destroy valuable pictures/documents.

Good luck!